# I'm having an issue getting getpass.getpass() under linux

Tags: python, linux

I've written a script on os x, importing getpass and asking for a password:

```
a = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
```

But when I run the same code in linux with:

```
python2 getpass.py
```

It says

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getpass'

I tried making a script like this:

```
import getpass
a = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
print a
```

I get:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Any ideas of what is wrong with getpass.getpass, since it works fine under os x?

Comment: What distro are you using, and what version of python?

Comment: Arch Linux - python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've named your script `getpass.py`, when you do `import getpass` you're importing yourself. This means that `getpass.getpass` resolves to the module, rather than the function you're intending to call in the `getpass` module in the standard library.

The solution is simple: Rename your script to something other than `getpass.py`. And in general, avoid using the same name as a standard library module for your own code (except perhaps in a package, if you're using `from __future__ import absolute_import` or a Python version where that's the default).

Comment: Good eye spotting that.

Comment: actually, that mistake I made in the second script, the first one is called "collections.py" and it returns:    

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getpass'

When I rename the second "getpass.py" script to "blabla.py" I get the same error above!

Comment: That doesn't make much sense with the code you've shown. Are you actually running something different? Perhaps with `from getpass import *` or something?

Comment: I was importing getpass in a wrong way. At first I had just
     import getpass
but later I added
     from getpass import getpass
after I took it out, the code ran smoothly.
Thanks very much for all the help !